# Percision of zero in a polynomial with transcendental number in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an unknown polynomial in two varaiables that I want to substitute one of the varaiables with a number but it has to be that it won't accidently be an exact zero of the polinomial.
Can I assume that if I give the following

```
for f=1:(length(var)-1)
    a_rand=rand(1);
    while a_rand==0
        a_rand=rand(1);
    end

    ply1=subs(poly1,var(f),a_rand*exp(2)/sqrt(3)*pi^7);
    ply2=subs(poly2,var(f),a_rand*exp(2)/sqrt(3)*pi^7);

end
```

That for sure it won't be zero(because it is a transcendental number)?
thanks

Comment: If the polynomial has _rational coefficients_, it's true that a transcendental number can't be a zero of that polynomial. But it can be _arbitrarily close_. A better approach would be to choose a tentative number (with any procedure) and then test that the polynomial evaluated at that number is sufficiently away from zero.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give me more information (or where to look) about tentative numbers? (I googled it and didn't find anything )

Comment: By "tentative" I mean "possible" or "candidate". My suggestion is you try some number and check if the result is very different from zero

Comment: Maybe it wasn't understood from the question. I do not no what is the polynomial. it can be a huge polynomial of a few variables.  by substituting a number instead of all except from one variable I can use sym2poly function. I can't check if I got a zero.

Comment: Your problem seems complex. can you elaborate a bit on why/how is that you cannot check the polynomials and what do you want to do with them after?

Comment: My function gets a polynomial of an unknown degree in two variables and some unknown coefficients. The out put is the Sylvester matrix relative to one of the coefficients. I use sym2poly() to find the coefficients of the variable that I'm using. sym2poly() can't handle more than one variable so I just substitute every parameter with this number so I can know if some of the coefficients are zero. Then I use coeffs() to get them. I don't use coeffs on the start because it doesn't give you zero coeffs, e.g $f=x^2+1$ will give [1 1] and I would assume it is $f=x+1$. Was I more understood? Thanks

Comment: Should I post the whole code?